# Changing space between answer choices in Qualtrics

Tags: css, qualtrics

I am using a new "skin" in Qualtrics where answer choices have a label wrapper, and there are no check boxes. Respondents actually click on the answer choice itself. Is there a way to reduce the size of the label wrapper so that the answer choices are closer together and the question is not so long vertically?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the padding on the labels:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
  $(this.questionId).select('label').each(function(name) {
    name.style.padding = "10px";
  });
});
```