# How can I add a space between two sets of answer choices in Qualtrics?

Tags: css, qualtrics

My question relates to visual formatting. Basically I would like to know how to visually separate answer choices within an item in Qualtrics.

Thus far I have tried to add an item and suppress the visibility of the text but that doesn't work, in that the text is not visible but the choice and its corresponding background color still exists. I have also tried to add padding and line breaks between the choices and that is not working either.

I know there is away to format the spacing between all of the choices ([Changing space between answer choices in Qualtrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33310519/changing-space-between-answer-choices-in-qualtrics)) but I cannot find out how to do it individually.

This is currently what I have: [image: Single group choices]

And this is what I would like to achieve: [image: Partitioned choices]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

---

Update: Here is what i have tried this far:

Hello,

I have tried dealing with the visibility of the text which obviously did not work:

```
<style> 

p.hidden 
    {visibility: 
     hidden
     } 
</style>

<p class=hidden>text</p>
```

I've also attempted to add line breaks after and before items just for spacing and that was a no go either. I'm sure this is something simple, but I am at a loss. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please tell/show us what you have tried.

Comment: Hi I have answered your question by updating my original post. I am relatively new to StackOverflow so I apologize if what I had up there was not in the correct format. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the nth-child pseudo selector.  Add the following to your question text (it will apply to all questions on the page) to add space before the 5th choice:

```
<style>
ul li:nth-child(5) {  
  margin-top: 20px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Oh this is perfect. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -2):

You can also paste this javascript for each question:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
var q = jQuery("#"+this.questionId);
q.find('li').last().css('margin-top', '20px');
q.find('li').last().css('display', 'block');


});
```